# I need help to display japanese character in a html page

Tags: html

I need help to display japanese character in a html page
I used in this code in head tag in html page but character is not showing properly.

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-JP" >
```

Comment: Have you tried this http://www.ehow.com/how_7337023_display-japanese-text-english-html.html

Comment: Does your text editor use the same encoding?

Comment: yes i have tried this but not working.

Comment: yes same encoding . I have set that by default.

Comment: What content type is being set in the HTTP headers?  The browser generally ignores `http-equiv`, how could it be parsing the page if it hadn't already decided on a character set?

Comment: i posted that code what i have had in html file.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying the code is irrelevant, it's the HTTP headers that matter.

Answer (score 1):

The probable cause is that your page is not actually EUC-JP encoded (or the browser used does not support that encoding, but that would be rare). Alternatively, the HTTP headers (which could be inferred from a URL, but not from a code snippet) might declare another encoding. It is also possible that the character used is not available in the fonts used, though this is not common these days.

Further information is needed to distinguish between these possibilities. Note that “not showing properly” could mean just about anything.

Answer (score -1):

Check if your browser/OS supports UTF-8:
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html